# Inspecting caller frames with gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, coredump

Suppose I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    if (a!=b)
        abort();
}
```

Compiled with:

```
 gcc -g c.c
```

Running this, I'll get a coredump (due to the `SIGABRT` raised by `abort()`), which I can debug with:

```
gdb a.out core
```

How can I get `gdb` to print the values of `a` and `b` from this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the another way to specifically get `a` and `b` values by moving to the interested *frame* and then `info locals` would give you the values.
`a.out` was compiled with your code. (frame 2 is what you are interested in i.e., `main()`).

```
$ gdb ./a.out core
[ removed some not-so-interesting info here ]
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
[New LWP 14732]
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007fac16269f5d in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00005592862f266d in main () at f.c:7
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00005592862f266d in main () at f.c:7
7               abort();
(gdb) info locals
a = 2
b = 3
(gdb) q
```

You can also use `print` once frame 2:

```
(gdb) print a
$1 = 2
(gdb) print b
$2 = 3
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I'll try and learn gdb a little bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Did you compile with debug symbols `-g`? The command should be `bt` for backtrace, you can also use `bt full` for a full backtrace.

More infos: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html

Comment: Thanks a  lot! `bt full` does show values! I'll wait a bit before accepting in case a more fine-grained method for this comes up.